# How create json file by object for send request in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I need to send a multipart request to server with a file (document_example.pdf) and a json file that contains the data object (data_object_example.json) in Angular 7.

data_object_example.json -> {
"attribute1": "name",
"attribute2": "second_name"
}

I know how create a multipart request, but I don't know how create json file by a object.

Thanks. ;)

**Answer:** Thanks to [HaiTH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3993983/haith)

```
const docJson = {
  fileDocType: file.name.split('?')[0].split('.').pop(),
  fileName: file.name
}
const fileJson = new File([JSON.stringify(docJson)], "file.json", {type: "application/json'"});

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('json', fileJson);
```

Comment: Why not just JSON.stringify() the data object and pass it as another field in the multipart request?

Comment: Hi, because I need to pass a File type json to server... and i can't change the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case you can't change backend and must create a file from client-side.
You can try this way:

```
const data = {someKey: 'value'};
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type: 'text/plain'});
const tmpFile = new File([blob], 'data_object_example.json');

// now you can pass this tmp file to a form with your pdf
const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', tmpFile);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this works! I've found another "easiest" way to do:
`const fileJson = new File([JSON.stringify(docJson)], "file.json", {type: "application/json'"}); `

Comment: Great that it could help.